# Breadth search algorithm implementation

Tags: python

I wrote a python code for **Breadth search algorithm** for 8 puzzle probelm. The states of the game are coded as a list of lists (two dimensional list). The goal is to reach `[[1,2,3],[8,0,4],[7,6,5]`] from a given state. The code output the path from a given state to the goal. It works fine but for this particular case `[[0,1,2],[7,8,3],[6,5,4]]` does not give the whole path rather it gives the last three states in the path.

Would you please try to point out the place of the bugs. Here is the code. Note The program starts from the statement:

```
"""
This program solves the 8 puzzel problems using Breadth First Search Algorithm.
"""

import copy

def successor(astate):
    """
    This function takes an instance of the 8 puzzel problem and generates all the legal successors.
    """
    up = copy.deepcopy(astate)
    """
    important note:
    I use [:] and list() to copy lists but it was not working fine, hence deecopy is used instead.
    """
    down = copy.deepcopy(astate)
    left = copy.deepcopy(astate)
    right = copy.deepcopy(astate)
    successors = []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if astate[i][j] == 0:
                row = i
                col = j
    if row != 0:
        dummy = up[row][col]
        up[row][col] = up[row -1][col]
        up[row-1][col] = dummy
        successors.append(up)
    if row != 2:
        dummy = down[row][col]
        down[row][col] = down[row+1][col]
        down[row+1][col] = dummy
        successors.append(down)
    if col != 2:
        dummy = right[row][col]
        right[row][col] = right[row][col+1]
        right[row][col+1] = dummy
        successors.append(right)
    if col != 0:
        dummy = left[row][col]
        left[row][col] = left[row][col-1]
        left[row][col-1] = dummy
        successors.append(left)
    return successors


def puzzle(astate):
    """
    This function takes a given instance of the 8 puzzel problem and returns the path to the goal where the goal is defined as below.
    """
    goal = [[1,2,3],[8,0,4],[7,6,5]]    #The goal state.
    generation = [astate]    #Nodes generated at each level.
    tracking = {}    #Track the path to the goal.
    path = []    #The path from the root to the goal.
    parent = generation.pop(0)    #Takes the first element of the list!!
    successors = successor(parent)    #Generate successors.
    key = str(parent)    #keys odictionaries must be hashable and mutable. Lists are illegal keys.
    tracking[key] = successors    #Associate successors with their parent.
    for asuccessor in successors:
        generation.append(asuccessor)    #Generate the first level.
    if goal in generation:    #if the goal is among the successors returns the path to it.
        path.insert(0, key)
        path.insert(0, goal)
        return path
    else:
        while generation != []:    #keep searching!
            parent = generation.pop(0)
            successors = successor(parent)    #generate successors 
            key = str(parent)
            tracking[key] = successors
            if goal in [astate for astate in successors]:    #if the goal is among the successors backtrack its path.
                path.insert(0, str(goal))    #Just because path contains states as strings!!
                path.insert(0, key)
                for key in tracking.keys():
                    for value in tracking.get(key):
                        if str(parent) == str(value):    #If the current (parent) is among the values of (key) then (key) is its parent.
                            path.insert(0, key)
                            parent = key
                            break
                return  path
            else:    #keep searching
                for asuccessor in successors:
                    if asuccessor not in generation:    #If the current successors is already generated do not add it.
                        if str(asuccessor) not in tracking.keys():    #If the successor is a previous parent do not add it.
                            generation.append(asuccessor)
        return
```

Comment: The problem you had with `[:]` is that it creates only a shallow copy of the object, and since the content of the `list` are `list` themselves they were shared. You could also do `[elem[:] for elem in the_list]`. Note that the list comprehension is about 25 times *faster* then `copy.deepcopy` on my machine with lists like yours. For the rest, I believe your question should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bakuriu: Codereview is **only** for **working code**. If the code does not work it will only be sent back here to be fixed first.